# Using an IR remote with a Nao robot

Tags: nao-robot

While attempting to set up an infrared remote control to connect with our Nao robot version 2.1.4, we've been receiving an error message as seen in the screen shot attached. We have followed the process as dictated under the tab on the Nao website titled Set Up Remote Control (http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/nao/remote-control.html) but keep receiving the error. We have tried saving the file as a comf file and also as a python file but neither has worked. What are the steps you recommend taking to get our remote control up and running? We are trying to attached an Apex-DT250 remote.

[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTZCz.png)

Comment: For years, I've never heard of someone using them, I think it's not really supported anymore. So good luck !